# Como copiar 2 textos con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código, pero no me funciona al querer copiar el segundo texto... alguien me podría ayudar, por favor???

Resulta que al darle clic al primer botón si se copia el primer texto, pero hago el mismo proceso en el segundo texto y no se copia, cambio el nombre de los id para que sean diferentes, pero aun así no funciona, alguien podría guiarme para hacerlo bien y que si se copie lo del segundo texto??

Acá esta mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 
 
<!-- inicio del texto1 -->
<div class="texto1">
<div id="textToCopy">
soy el texto 1
</div>
<br>
<button id="copyButton">Click para copiar</button> <span id="copyResult"></span>
</div>
<br>
 
<script>
 
  const answer = document.getElementById("copyResult");
const copy   = document.getElementById("copyButton");
const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = document.createRange();
const textToCopy = document.getElementById("textToCopy")
 
copy.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    range.selectNodeContents(textToCopy);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    if(successful){
      answer.innerHTML = 'Copiado!';
    } else {
      answer.innerHTML = 'No se pudo copiar!';
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
});
 
</script>
 
<style>
  .texto1{
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
</style>
 
<!-- final del texto1 -->
 
<div class="texto2">
<div id="textToCopy">
soy el texto 2
</div>
<br>
<button id="copyButton1">Click para copiar</button> <span id="copyResult1"></span>
</div>
 
<script>
 
  const answer = document.getElementById("copyResult1");
const copy   = document.getElementById("copyButton1");
const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = document.createRange();
const textToCopy = document.getElementById("textToCopy1")
 
copy.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    range.selectNodeContents(textToCopy);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    if(successful){
      answer.innerHTML = 'Copiado!';
    } else {
      answer.innerHTML = 'No se pudo copiar!';
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
});
 
</script>
 
<style>
  .texto2{
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
</style>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

De entrada, tienes dos elementos `<div id="textToCopy">` y eso ya es suficiente para que no funcione el segundo botón, pero no es todo, si revisas la consola, deberías ver errores por querer volver a definir las constantes, por ejemplo `const textToCopy = document...` no puedes usar nuevamente el mismo nombre y, suponiendo que las declares con `var`, simplemente vas a remplazar las creadas previamente y solo va a funcionar uno de los botones.

Te sugiero crear una función que reciba ID del elemento que se va a copiar e ID del que va a mostrar el resultado.

```js
// Todo dentro de una función
function copyText(idOrigin, idDest) {
    // Las constantes solo están disponibles dentro, no se sobreescriben
    const textToCopy = document.getElementById(idOrigin);
    const answer = document.getElementById(idDest);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(textToCopy);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);

    // Todo funciona correctamente
    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    if(successful){
      answer.innerHTML = 'Copiado!';
    } else {
      answer.innerHTML = 'No se pudo copiar!';
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
}

// Asignas evento al primer botón
document.querySelector('#copyButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Ejecutas la función enviando ID de elemento a copiar e ID de elemento donde se mostrará el resultado
    copyText('textToCopy', 'copyResult');
});

// Asignas evento al segundo botón
document.querySelector('#copyButton1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Ejecutas la función enviando ID de elemento a copiar e ID de elemento donde se mostrará el resultado
    copyText('textToCopy1', 'copyResult1');
});
```

```css
  .texto1{
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
  .texto2{
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- inicio del texto1 -->
<div class="texto1">
<div id="textToCopy">
soy el texto 1
</div>
<br>
<button id="copyButton">Click para copiar</button> <span id="copyResult"></span>
</div>
<br>
 

<div class="texto2">
<div id="textToCopy1">
soy el texto 2
</div>
<br>
<button id="copyButton1">Click para copiar</button> <span id="copyResult1"></span>
</div>
```

**Nota:** Para asignar evento a los botones usé `document.querySelector('#copyButton')` que es equivalente de `document.getElementById('copyButton')`, pero me resulta más fácil de usar.